# Upgrading Visual Studio Yields - 'IAsyncOperation': base class undefined and IID_IAsyncOperation undefined

Tags: c++, visual-studio, mfc

I'm testing VS2017 to see if I can move to it from VS2008 (I think we can drop Win9x now but still need NT4) and all is looking pretty favorable building the libraries, but one won't build due to the `'IAsyncOperation': base class undefined` and `IID_IAsyncOperation undefined` errors.  I thought maybe because I didn't install MFC in the initial install, so went back in and added MFC, but still have the problem.  I searched the include directories and couldn't find it either.  Searching Internet, no luck.  So is there a direct replacement for those (I'd like to wrap them in an #if so I can still build with V2008 if needed).

TIA!!

Answer (score 1):

Finally found it:

```
#if _MSC_VER >= 1900
#include "Shldisp.h"
#define IAsyncOperation IDataObjectAsyncCapability
#define IID_IAsyncOperation IID_IDataObjectAsyncCapability
#endif
```

Comment: *"Finally found it"* - What's that supposed to mean? You found this in SDK/MFC headers as a replacement? You found a solution to your problem? If it is the latter, then you are using the wrong check. Whether symbols are declared or not is a property of the SDK, not the IDE/compiler you are using. Also, since this is C++, you may want to favor [`using`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/type_alias) over preprocessor definitions.

Comment: The answer to "So is there a direct replacement for those (I'd like to wrap them in an #if so I can still build with V2008 if needed)"?

Comment: This neither explains the answer nor is it the correct solution. Once you switch to a more recent SDK in your VS 2008 build you'll run into the same issue all over again.

Comment: I installed VS2013 and ran into this exact issue. For some reason I cannot explain the definition of 'IAsyncOperation' is missing though I have not run into this before with previous installs. I'm up-voting as this lets me move on to more important things. :)